# Increase distance between points in a categorical X axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, graphics

I am using `geom_point` in combination with `position_dodge` to plot points and spread them a bit in the horizontal axis. The problem is that the points of a benchmark are too close to the points of another benchmark (i.e. atax and bicg).

How do I increase the distance between ticks in the X-axis when the axis is categorical? Or how do I prevent the points of different benchmarks from touching each other.

Below is the code that I used to produce the figure on [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NNGGH.png)

```
ggplot(data = df, aes(x = Benchmark, y = time, shape = type)) +
    theme_light() +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
    scale_shape_manual(values = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4)) +
    geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 1), color = 'gray60', size = 2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `expand` argument in `scale_x_discrete`, adding a line to the plot that looks like `scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0.2, 0.2))` and playing with the values.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've tried that but the result doesn't look professional at all! 
https://imgur.com/4JP7ZPt . Ideally, I would like to use `position="dodge"` with `geom_point` and this would produce the same result as if I was using `geom_bar`.

Comment: What about using `geom_jitter()` instead of `geom_point()` ? That should fix the overlapping issue, that I think is the main problem right?

Comment: the problem with `geom_jitter()` is that I want points of the same type to be jittered by the same amount in the horizontal axis but `geom_jitter()` will shift every point by a random amount. By the way, here is the result with `geom_jitter()`: https://imgur.com/XQqBkfR